# "Ask question" left border visible on main site

Tags: bug, design

I've been noticing this for the last few days, and it seems like a bug.

Here is what the link currently looks like:

[image: Ask question - main site]

Notice the dark purple colored left border which shouldn't be visible. Below is the zoomed image:

[image: Ask question - zoomed]

While hovering, the border disappears.

[image: Ask question - hover]

There is no such border on meta.

[image: Ask question - metsa]

This is a very minor bug, and I guess it should not take more than a minute to fix.